# String Append with LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a List names = new List {"aa", "bb", "cc"}. I want to use the LINQ way and appennd a string to each one of them (instead of String builder and a foreach loop specifically). So the final output would be as follows:

```
names[0] = aaxyz
names[1] = bbxyz
names[2] = ccxyz
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using a Select:

```
var names2 = names.Select(i => i + "yz");
```

This will create a list of string with "yz" appended to each. If you then want to concatenate into a single string, you can use a Linq aggregate:

```
var nameString = names2.Aggregate((current, next) => current + " " + next);
```

However, personally, I would use a foreach and StringBuilder in this context. More readable and better performance!